# How to extract success ratio for knn classifier

Tags: matlab, image-processing, knn

I am trying to implement a knn classifier for eigen-faces as a home assignment (matlab).

I have a weights matrix `weights` extracted from a test matrix and eigen vectors `eVectors` and a vector of labels `train_face_id`.

First of is this a correct way to construct the classifier?

```
%project the test set to the eigenfaces space
projections=eVectors*weights;
%construct the classifier 
mdl=fitcknn(weights,train_face_id,'Standardize',1);
```

Secondly (and this is the main question) I am requested to say "What are the success ratios (for face_id)?". Is that what I get from `rloss=resubLoss(mdl);`? If not how do I extract the success ratios?